# Android WebView - reset HTTP session

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a WebView in an Android app. I periodically to be able to reset the WebView http session so that the server app it is accessing will initialise a new session. I can't find how to do this - is this possible ?

Rgds, Kevin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the clear cookie can make session close. More about [session](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1499-Session-A-Concept-for-Beginners.aspx)

```
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Comment: First line is deprecated / not needed. `removeAllCookie` method is deprecated too, we now use `removeAllCookies` (note the S at the end), sending a (nullable) callback function as parameter

Answer (score 3):

```
import android.webkit.CookieManager;

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
```

**`removeSessionCookie()`** allows to keep other cookies but clear sessions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you can do to clear the webview depending exactly what you want to do:

[webView.clearCache(true);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache%28boolean%29)

[webView.clearHistory();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearHistory%28%29)

[webView.destroy();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#destroy%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()
```